# Change the default values of aspect_ratios SSD to my own values

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection

In the SSD512 object detection model the  default values of aspect_ratios are :

```
aspect_ratios_per_layer=[[1.0, 2.0, 0.5],
[1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 3.0, 1.0/3.0],
[1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 3.0, 1.0/3.0],
[1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 3.0, 1.0/3.0],
[1.0, 2.0, 0.5, 3.0, 1.0/3.0],
[1.0, 2.0, 0.5],
[1.0, 2.0, 0.5]],
```

But i want to have these values :  `[1.0 , 1.0/4.0 , 1.0/3.0 , 0.5 , 3.0/4.0 ]`

Now i want to replace these values with my own values , How do I add these to the layers? Why in the first layer don't exist 1.0/3.0 value and so on , What are the rules for the layers selected?